# How to initiate array items using for loop in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Python allows programmers to perform such an operation:

```
mylist = [1, 2]
items = [value * 2 for value in namelist]
```

How can I achieve the same using Kotlin, I want to pass values multiplied by 2 from `mylist` into the array below:

```
val mylist = mutableListOf(1, 2)
val (first, second) = arrayOf( )
```

Kotlin allows us to to declare and initiate variables with one liners as below

`val (first, second) = arrayOf(1, 2)` that way you can call `first` or `second` as a variable. Am trying to make the `equal part` dynamic

Comment: `Am trying to make the equal part dynamic`. Are you saying you want to create these variables like `first`, `second` dynamically?

Comment: @Arpit Shukla Exactly

Comment: Creating variables at run time isn't possible. Why do you need to do that? Can you share an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent of the above Python code in Kotlin is:

```kotlin
val mylist = listOf(1, 2)
val items = mylist.map { it * 2 }
```

If you need to assign resulting doubled values to `first` and `second`, then do it exactly as you did:

```kotlin
val (first, second) = mylist.map { it * 2 }
```

You need to be sure `myList` contains at least 2 items.

Comment: I'm not sure about your example Kotlin code. It seems unrelated to what you do in Python.

Comment: I have edited my question to address this concern

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you mean. You first speak about creating an array/list from another list and then you jump into unpacking/destructuring into `first`/`second`, which is pretty unrelated thing. If you just wanted to use both of these features at the same time then see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
// === KOTLIN

var mylist = listOf(1, 2)

            
val result = mylist.map { it * 2 }

println(result)
// output: [ 2,4 ]
```